# CSS: Forcing blocks to appear under a float block if they overflow

Tags: css-float, css

I'm creating a page with an image with several blocks of text next to it.  I don't want the blocks of text to wrap, because that looks bad.  But I also don't want to add "overflow: hidden" because that looks bad (specifically, the end of the block of text hangs past the image).

What I would like to do, and I don't know how, is to force the block to render under the floating element if it will overflow.  That way the block of text stays together (unlike allowing the overflow) AND it doesn't hang off the end all funny (like with "overflow:hidden").

Here's some html to demonstrate my problem.

```
<head>
<style>
.imgclass {background-color:336633;width:100px;color:00000;float:left}
p {overflow:hidden;width:100px}
</style> 
</head>

<div class="imgclass">Pretend there is an image here. Pretend there is an image 
here. Pretend there is an image here. Pretend there is an image here. Pretend 
there is an image here.
</div>

<p>
This is a paragraph.  It looks good next to the pretend image.
</p>

<p>   
This is a paragraph.  It hangs off the pretend image and looks bad.  I wish that 
if the paragraph was too long it would appear under the image.
</p>
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?  Perhaps I shouldn't use float?

Also: I'm making a general css.  I have no idea how big the image will be or how long the paragraphs will be.

Answer (score 0):

here is the update - 
css

```
.imgclass {background-color:336633;width:100px;color:00000;float:left}
p {
    width:100%;
}
.long{
    clear: left;
}
```

html

```
<div class="imgclass">Pretend there is an image here. Pretend there is an image 
here. Pretend there is an image here. Pretend there is an image here. Pretend 
there is an image here.
</div>

<p>
This is a paragraph.  It looks good next to the pretend image.
</p>

<p class="long">   
This is a paragraph.  It hangs off the pretend image and looks bad.  I wish that 
if the paragraph was too long it would appear under the image.
</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  I want to know how to make the blocks of text appear under the image if they will overflow.  Changing the width makes the particular example not overflow, but that's not what I'm asking.